# Examples of Equal Mass, Unequal Mass and Double Binary Star Systems

Tags: binary-star

Can anyone give me an example of a star (ideally those with a common name e.g. Rigel, Sirius, etc) of the following multiple star systems.

Equal Mass Star System, where two binary stars orbit round a central point of space.

Unequal Mass Star System, where a smaller star(s) orbits round a larger binary star.

Double Binary where two sets of binary stars orbit round a spot. (Regulus?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Equal mass

**[Alpha Centauri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Centauri)**, the nearest star system to us, is composed of a binary star and Proxima Centauri (making it a triple star system). Alpha Centauri A has a mass of 1.1 M$_{\odot}$, while Alpha Centauri B has a mass of 0.9 M$_{\odot}$.

If you count brown dwarfs, **[Luhman 16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhman_16) are a good target, with each being about 0.04 M$_{\odot}$**.

## Unequal mass

**[Eta Carinae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_Carinae)** contains a Luminous Blue Variable (LBV) with a mass of 120-160 M$_{\odot}$ and a smaller (but still very massive) star with a mass of 30-60 M$_{\odot}$.

**[Sirius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius)** is okay, though with two stars of much smaller masses, 2 M$_{\odot}$ and 1 M$_{\odot}$.

## Double binary

**[Mizar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizar_and_Alcor)**, in reality part of a six-star system (Mizar/Alcor), has four stars separated into two pairs. This  ensemble then interacts with the binary star Alcor.

---

You can find plenty of stars [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_system).

Comment: Thanks HDE, I did notice Wikipedia page but it couldn't see what I exactly wanted.